# Excel - Can't get formula to work when nesting functions, but works if I keep them separated in different cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My issue is currently that I can't get a formula to work with all 3 formulas nested into a single cell, my workaround that I'm trying to stop having to do is using hidden columns and having each hidden column do 1 of the 3 formulas, then referencing the final value.

My 3 formulas are as follows:

1. **Step 1** `=FILTER(Calculations!H$8:H$39,Calculations!B$8:B$39='Updated Version'!C9,"")`
2. **Step 2** `=INDEXLIST(L9,",",'Updated Version'!D9)` (*note - INDEXLIST is a user defined function* [source](https://www.howtoexcel.org/how-to-find-the-nth-item-in-a-comma-separated-list/))
3. **Step 3** `=IFERROR(M9,0)`

Basically, **Step 1** returns a comma separated list of values (e.g. "1", "1,2,3"), **Step 2** then gets the value from the index I tell it to (index is 'Updated Version'!D9), and **Step 3** just returns the value from Step 2 or 0 if there was an error.

If I try to combine all of this into one formula (shown below), it doesn't work. It returns 0 because of `=iferror({...}, 0)`, if I remove `iferror` then there is a #VALUE! error but I'm not sure why:

**Formulas nested**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEXLIST(FILTER(Calculations!H$8:H$39,Calculations!B$8:B$39='Updated Version'!C10,""),",",'Updated Version'!D10),0)
```

Thank you for any advice, apologies for the cryptic/difficult to read formulas.

Comment: I believe step 1 is returing an array, but step 2 is looking for a deliminated string. if available, wrap step 1 with `ARRAYTOTEXT()` or 'TEXTJOIN()`. Another option is to update the UDF to include all steps in it.

Comment: can we see a mock up of the data, the FILTER will not concatenate so there must be another step if you are concatenating the values to a comma separated list.

Comment: Yes! @gns100 thanks. I had realized that was it was after posting, but I was using `=concat("", <value>, "")` and I like `ARRAYTOTEXT` better. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @ScottCraner I think that was exactly it, I didn't realize `indexlist` wanted a value like "1,2,3" not 1,2,3. Once I used `arraytotext`, everything's working right.

Comment: sorry mistyped INDEX takes an array and can return the nth value in the array: `=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(Calculations!H$8:H$39,Calculations!B$8:B$39='Updated Version'!C9,""),'Updated Version'!D9),0)`

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm actually struggling to use index(). I'd like to use index if possible, and avoid using the user-defined-function indexlist(). I'm trying to use index like so as an example, and would expect a 2 from the following: `=index(1,2,3, 2)` but I think I'm misunderstanding how to use this. Since my "array" isn't really an array, but rather it's a comma separated list of values e.g. 1,2,3 is `index` still usable?

Comment: do not convert to a comma delimited string.  Filter will return an array and index will use that.  It is similar to `=INDEX({1,2,3},2)`  Where `{1,2,3}` is an array and not a comma separated string.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm in a bit of a weird situation where my filter is actually returning a single cell from another sheet, and that value is already a comma-separated string like 1,2,3.

Comment: do you have TEXTSPLIT: `=IFERROR(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(FILTER(Calculations!H$8:H$39,Calculations!B$8:B$39='Updated Version'!C9,""),","),'Updated Version'!D9),0)`